# DFA for strings not containing 101101 as substring

Tags: finite-automata, dfa

Given language `L={ w | w belongs to (0,1)*, w does not contain the substring 101101}`, Construct the DFA for this.

I understand that if I could draw the DFA for set of all strings over `(0,1)*` such that `101101` is a substring then I could simply use complementation to find the required DFA ..

Can anyone help me with the construction of DFA for L

Comment: Looks like you already have a strategy. What specific problem are you having when trying to create your DFA?

Answer (score 0):

I think this DFA will satisfy your requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is right. Here are the steps written out:

First, make a DFA for the language of all strings containing 101101 as a substring. All such strings can begin and end with anything, so long as they have 101101 somewhere in between. In other words, a regular expression for this language is `(0+1)*101101(0+1)*`. A DFA looks like this:

```
    |
    |
    |  /-0-\
    V /    |
   (q0)<---+
    |      |
    1      |
    |      |
    V      |
   (q1)--1-+
    |      |
    0      |
    |      |
    V      |
   (q2)--0-+
    |      |
    1      |
    |      |
    V      |
   (q3)--0-+
    |      |
    1      |
    |      |
    V      |
   (q4)--1-+
    |      |
    0      |
    |      |
    V      |
   (q5)--0-+
    |
    1
    |
    V
  [[q6]]<-\
     |    |
     \-0,1/
```

State `[[q6]]` is the accepting state since that's where you end up if you see the necessary substring.

Second, we need to take the complement. For a DFA, this is easy: we change all accepting states to non-accepting, and vice-versa. So, our new DFA looks the same, but has `(q6)` non-accepting and `[[q0]]`, `[[q1]]`, `[[q2]]`, `[[q3]]`, `[[q4]]`, `[[q5]]` accepting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for your question. First draw DFA which accepts 101101 as string. Then change the non-final states to final states and final states to non-final states. That's it,the required DFA is ready.You will get a DFA which doesn't accept 101101 string.
[click here to view DFA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIS4m.jpg)